# Как можно отрендерить массив из State для отоброжения в dom

Tags: reactjs

```
    this.state = {
      components: [
          {
              id:1, name: 'Some Name'
          }
      ]
  }
```

как вывести все значение свойства в dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mol16l8rv9?fontsize=14)**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: [
      {
        id: 1, name: 'Some Name'
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.components.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>id: {item.id}, name: {item.name}</div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для рендера массивов в react можно использовать Array.prototype.map()

Здесь подробно можешь об этом почитать, но на английском: [React lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)